# Sitecore Powershell create new language version does not include layouts for final layout

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I'm trying to use Sitecore Powershell extensions to add a new language version. I run a command like the following from the console:
"Add-ItemVersion -Path "PATH" -TargetLanguage "LANGUAGE""

The New item gets created but the layouts on the "final layout" tabs are missing on the new version.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The "Final Layout" is language and version specific, so it makes sense that it would be empty when creating a new language version. Some options you have:

- Use Shared Layout instead, if you just want the same layout across languages.
- Add additional SPE code to copy the Final Layout from the 'en' version, if you want the have different layout but provide a starting point.
- You *might* be able to use Language Fallback on the Final Layout field, but I have not attempted this myself. But really, this is what the Shared Layout is intended to do.

More information on [versioned layouts](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/versioned_layouts/versioned_layouts) can be found in Sitecore documentation.

Comment: But as far as I understand the final layout is a combination of the shared layouts and then the layouts you and specific for a version. My new version final layout is completely empty. If I add a new version manually in Sitecore it works fine, but I dont wanna do that for an entire site.

Comment: Does the item have shared layout or version-specific layout, or both? The version-specific values are stored in the __Final renderings field, which is what I assumed you were referring to.

Comment: Shared layout and final layout but they're the same. The manually created version have both final and shared aswell. SPE only have Shared Layout and therefor I'm getting a "no layout found" error

Comment: When you look at Raw Values, what do you see in the __renderings and __final renderings fields?

Comment: The original item's raw values on _final renderings are empty, so that explains why it doesn't appear on the new version. hmmm..so I need to find a way to avoid getting "no layout error"